# How to implement a horizontal carousel scroller like allrecipies

Tags: ios

how do apps like allrecipies, or the bbc news website, implement the horizontal scrolling?

[image: horizonal scrolling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with horizontal tableviews.

There are a few examples if you search for them. Such as [EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView) or [HorizontalTable](https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable) etc.